# How to use existing entity in a Symfony2 form?

Tags: forms, symfony, nested-forms, symfony-forms, tagging

I've this two entities:

```
class Article
{
    /** @var ArrayCollection
    protected $tags;
}

class Tag
{
    protected $id;
    protected $name;
}
```

Basically I've read http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/form_collections.html but it does not explain my case.

Let me explain.

I've existing tags in database, so I want to be able to associate multiple Tags to my Article, I don't want to allow the creation of inexistent tags.

Since I'm aiming to use my form in both a REST api and with a web form, I'd like my client be able to use the `id` only to reference the tags (which would have been fetched before).

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [entity field typ](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html)e. It is in practice a *choice field type* that you can render as a *select* with multiple selection or as a *list of checkboxes*. However, if you have many tags there will be too many options and the users will not be happy.

So, I suggest to implement a **Stackoverflow-like** tagging system.

I did it in a project by using a Javascript tokeninput library, like this by [loopj](https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput).
In practice:

1. You should first render a text field named `tags`.
2. Then you should handle the tag insertion to that input field with the Javascript library for token handling.
3. The Controller will receive a tokenized string that you have to handle in order to retrieve the `Tag` entities from Doctrine.
4. Finally, retrieved a list of `Tag` entities, assign them to your `Article` entity and flush everything.

Answer (score 1):

You can use somethig like this:

```
$builder->add('tags', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'AcmeHelloBundle:tag',
    'expanded' => true,
    'multiple' => true,
));
```

Comment: Yes, as I suggested! However, it is not useful in practice when you have dozens of tags! Imagine the amount of tags in Stackoverflow shown in a unique select!